# How do I use a windows batch command to copy an artefact from an old build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins project and using the promotions plugin I am able to promote a build and copy an artefact from the target directory to a remote share using the windows batch command. I do this:

```
net use \\remoteserver\$myshare myUser /user:myPass
copy /y target\myartefact.apk \\remoteserver\$myshare\myartefact.apk
```

This works fine and copies the artefact. However, it copies from the current workspace (ie the latest build).

So if I go and promote an old build, it doesn't copy the artefact from that build, it copies from the current workspace/latest build.

I know that I probably need to change the following line in the windows batch command:

```
copy /y target\myartefact.apk \\remoteserver\$myshare\myartefact.apk
```

However, what do I change it to? What environment variable/path do I use to reference the build directory instead of **target\myartefact.apk**

I'm assuming I need something like:

```
copy /y %JOB_NAME%\target\myartefact.apk \\remoteserver\$myshare\myartefact.apk
```

Can anyone help with this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out and was able to access the relevant build archive using the following copy command:

```
copy /y ..\builds\%PROMOTED_ID%\archive\target\myartefact.apk \\remoteserver\$myshare\myartefact.apk
```

Note that the %PROMOTED_ID% environment variable is the directory of the original build when using the promotion plugin. It replaces the usual %BUILD_ID% environment variable. So if you are not using the promotion plugin, you can access your old build artefacts with the following: `..\builds\%BUILD_ID%\archive\target\myartefact.apk`